# Congruence relation instead of arrow

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
\[
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \matrix(m)[
     matrix of math nodes,
     column sep=1cm
  ]{0 & E[m]/mE(K) & H^1(G_{\bar{K}/K},E[m])) &  H^1(G_{\bar{K}/K},E)[m] & 0.\\
    &  &  & WC(E/K) &  \\};
\foreach[count=\i,evaluate={\j=int(\i+1)}]\text in {{},{$\delta$},${}$,{}}
\path[-angle 90,font=\scriptsize](m-1-\i)edge node[above]{\text}(m-1-\j);
\end{tikzpicture}
\]
```

I have this so far. How do I add in a congruence relation symbol `$\cong$` between `$H^1(G_{\bar{K}/K},E)[m]$` and `$WC(E/K)$` while not changing anything else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option using a node with rotate content; I also used the perpendicular coordinate system so your arrows are truly horizontal:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows}

\begin{document}


\[
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \matrix(m)[
     matrix of math nodes,
     column sep=1cm,
     row sep=6pt
  ]
  {
  0 & E[m]/mE(K) & H^1(G_{\bar{K}/K},E[m])) &  H^1(G_{\bar{K}/K},E)[m] & 0.\\
    &  &  & WC(E/K) &  \\
  };
\foreach[count=\i,evaluate={\j=int(\i+1)}]\text in {{},{$\delta$},${}$,{}}
\path[-angle 90,font=\scriptsize](m-1-\i.east)edge node[above]{\text}(m-1-\j.west|-m-1-\i.east);
\node[rotate=-90] at ([yshift=-3pt]m-1-4.south) {$\cong$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a way to make the $\cong$ longer?